# Filter Recyclerview From Array of objects Android

Tags: android

i have RecyclerView get data from Array of objects , and i tried to make Filter in Recycler View adapter like this ,

```
    public void filter(String filterString) {
    filterString = filterString.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
    results.clear();
    if(filterString.length() == 0) {
    }
    else {
        for( ToDo item : stringArrayList){
            if(item.getTODO_TITLE().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(filterString)) {
                results.add(item.getTODO_TITLE() );
            }
        }
    }
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

}

and when i call it in menu like this

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_search, menu);
    MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);
    searchView.setOnQueryTextFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {

        }
    });

    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {

            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String searchQuery) {

            if (searchQuery.length() != 0) {
                if (null != recyclerAdapter) {
                    recyclerAdapter.filter(searchQuery.toString());
                    todoRecyclerView.invalidate();
                    todoAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
            else{
            }
            return false;
        }
    });


    MenuItemCompat.setOnActionExpandListener(searchItem, new MenuItemCompat.OnActionExpandListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem item) {
            return true;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem item) {
            return true;
        }
    });
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.action_search) {

        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}}
```

its not working , and no error is showing !!! how i can solve this problem ????

this is my code into recycler

```
public class TodoList extends AppCompatActivity implements DialogFragUpdateListener {
RecyclerView todoRecyclerView;
private RecyclerView.Adapter todoAdapter;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager todoLayoutManager;
public List<ToDo> results;
public List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
TodoRecyclerAdapter recyclerAdapter;
Context context;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_todo_list);

    todoRecyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.todoRecyclerView);
    todoRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    results= new ArrayList<ToDo>();
    todoLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    todoRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(todoLayoutManager);
      getRetrofitObject();
    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(TodoList.this,AddToDo.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });}

public void getRetrofitObject() {
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
    APIService service = retrofit.create(APIService.class);
    Call<Result> call = service.getresults();
    call.enqueue(new Callback<Result>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Result> call, Response<Result> response) {
            results = response.body().getResults();
            todoRecyclerView.setAdapter(new TodoRecyclerAdapter(this,results));
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Result> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.d("onFailure", t.toString());
        }});}
```

Recycler View **Adpater**

```
public class TodoRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TodoRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder>  {

static List<ToDo> todoResults;
static Context context;
List<String> results;
private List<String> mDefaultCheeses;
private List<ToDo> mData;
private List<ToDo> originalData;
private ArrayList<ToDo> arrayList = null, stringArrayList;


public TodoRecyclerAdapter(Callback<Result> callback, List<ToDo> results) {
    this.todoResults = results;
     arrayList= (ArrayList<ToDo>) results;

}

@Override
public TodoRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemLayoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.todo_items, null);
    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(itemLayoutView);
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final TodoRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    holder.todoTitle.setText(todoResults.get(position).getTODO_TITLE().toString());
    String priority = todoResults.get(position).getPriority().toString();
    if (priority.equals("Low")) {
        holder.todoImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.low);
    } else if (priority.equals("Normal")) {
        holder.todoImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.normal);
    } else if (priority.equals("High")) {
        holder.todoImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.high);
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return todoResults.size();
}

public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView todoTitle;
    public ImageView todoImage;

    public ViewHolder(View itemLayoutView) {
        super(itemLayoutView);
        todoTitle = (TextView) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.todo_title);
        todoImage = (ImageView) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
    }
}

public void filter(String filterString) {
    filterString = filterString.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
    results.clear();
    if(filterString.length() == 0) {
    }
    else {
        for( ToDo item : stringArrayList){
            if(item.getTODO_TITLE().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(filterString)) {
                results.add(item.getTODO_TITLE() );
            }
        }
    }
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

}

Comment: use [this](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/pskink/cd3bbdd742b5b1905a790c76831b5d85/raw/89a41acded0889028be48e1f669562046cf66126/MatchableRVArrayAdapte%2520(pure%2520RecyclerView%2520style,%2520no%2520implicit%2520TextView%2520mapping)) generic adapter

Comment: Thank you .. but how to apply this in my case? Please

Comment: filter items like in normal ListView: `adapter.getFilter().filter(...)` and of course override `matches` method

Comment: I do this but not working

Comment: What "not working"?

Comment: When run the app .. and try to use this .. the result is nothing

Comment: post your code then

Comment: @pskink I post my adapter full code please help !!

Comment: i dont see any adapter that extends `MatchableRVArrayAdapter`

Comment: I don't know how to apply you solution in my code but I post my all code , if you need it !

Comment: extend it and override `matches` method: `class TodoAdapter extends MatchableRVArrayAdapter<ToDo, TodoAdapter.VH> {...`

Comment: where ??? I cannot understand what you exactly mean !

Comment: what where? do you know how to extend some class?

Comment: yes sure I now ok I will do this on my adapter

Comment: I add "MatchableRVArrayAdapter" with full code , now what i can do ? can you answer me ? what exactly  do in the adapter ?

Comment: override `matches` method and do filtering like that: `adapter.getFilter().filter(...)` inside `onQueryTextChange`

Comment: hmmm iam sorry for that , but how to extend this ??

Comment: `class TodoAdapter extends MatchableRVArrayAdapter<ToDo, TodoAdapter.VH> {...`

Comment: not working , can you post answer of my adapter ? please and sure I will accept your answer , I know iam Bothered you but this is very important for me please post answer with all solution

Comment: what is not working? did you extend MatchableRVArrayAdapter? what is your code then?

Comment: This extends for my adapter its wrong

Comment: what is wrong? what is yopur adapter code?

Comment: I post my adapter TodoRecyclerAdapter

Comment: so [here](http://pastebin.com/DZTwyFbC) you have sample adapter

Comment: ok after extends this , how to override method ? and how to call it into menu ??

Comment: what methods? did you see the code of sample adapter i posted? it is a full working code, all you need is to `add()` data to that adapter

Comment: its not working for me , I don't know exactly what I do , so thank you for every thing :)

Comment: whats not working? did you use the adapter i posted? did you `add()` some `ToDo` objects to that adapter?

Comment: I cannot now how to use it , and ask you to post answer with edit my adapter because iam beginner in android and cannot understand how to make this ,

Comment: you have to call `MatchableRVArrayAdapter#add` method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the error isn't in the logs because you aren't adding elements to results. You must log your code and see what is happening there.
Maybe this will help you:
In your `filter` method try this:

```
ArrayList<Note> result;
List<ToDO>itemsCopy = new ArrayList<>();

private void filter(String text){

        itemsCopy= items in results arraylist

        result = new ArrayList<>();
        text = text.toLowerCase();
        for(ToDO item: itemsCopy){
            if(item.getTitle().toLowerCase().contains(text)){
                result.add(item);
            }
        }
        results.clear();
        results.addAll(result);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
        //Log your code! Always helps
        Log.i(TAG, "---RESULT--" +result.toString());

}
```

Then in `OnCreateOptionsMenu`:

```
@Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                filter(query);

                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                filter(newText);

                return true;
            }
        });
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: thank you , but itemsCopy ? what is it ? I will edit my question and add my adapter and please apply this for my case

Comment: where you create filter method ?? in main activity ? or on adapter ???? please tell me !!

Comment: after I do all steps and no error , I got this error when run the app > 

 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                               java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                                   at com.example.todo.loginretroft.Activites.TodoList.filter(TodoList.java:187)


TodoList.java:187 =         todoAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: I will post my Activity with full code , and please try to help me @neo